# CSS: how do I position my slideshow counter up into the slideshow

Tags: css

I've been fighting with this one CSS issue.

[Here is the site](http://surety.lfwebz.com/) I working. [learning drupal, css, etc., so ignore design], see the image counter just below the slideshow, right now, just 1, 2.  I want that counter to display inside the image, bottom right.

I have tried everything that I can think of, positioning, padding, bottom.

How do I move the counter up into the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
.views-slideshow-controls-bottom{
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Wow that got and I will go on and admit, I was using position: absolute, more reading to do.  THanks so much!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Change the margins of the counter. In this case, something like margin-top: -50px, margin-left:20px, z-index:999, position:relative (not exact numbers) should achieve what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Also add the cursor point `cursor:pointer;` enjoy.